# Returns keys as string of an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, google-tag-manager

I have an array of objects and I need the keys of all objects that appear in this array. I work with Google Tag Manager templates and this uses a Sandboxed version of JavaScript. Therefore, some functions, like RegEx, are not present.

My array:

```
var products: [{
        'name': 'Test Product 1',         
        'variant': 'Blue'
       },
       {
        'name': 'Test Product 2',         
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
       }]
```

As you can see, some keys are present for product 1 but not for product 2. This is works as attended. Whenever one key is present here, we want that key back as a (list of) strings. I'm trying to create the following:

```
'name, id, variant, price'
```

I've tried converting the array to a string. However, this makes the array messy. And since .replace() doesn't always work and RegEx is not present it's hard to clean the string.

This happens when I convert the array to a string.

```
var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(ourArray);

//output "[\\"id","name"\"\]"
```

Any suggestions for my issue?

Comment: what do you mean `\\ \" \"` in your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

I just looked over the Google Tag Manager [API](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/api) and didn't realize how restrictive it is.

As a result it seems that the following is a viable solution. It relies on overwriting duplicate keys in the accumulator object in a reduce call to avoid duplicates in the result.

It uses the [Object](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/api#object) methods `keys` and `entries`, and [Array](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/templates/standard-library#array) methods `reduce`, `forEach`, and `join`, all of which are available, and doesn't need `Array#includes` or a `Set` which aren't.

```js
const products = [{ 'name': 'Test Product 1', 'variant': 'Blue' }, { 'name': 'Test Product 2', 'id': '12345', 'price': '15.25', }]

const keys = Object.keys(products.reduce((a, o) => {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(function (entry) { a[entry[0]] = entry[1] });
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(keys.join(', '));
```

---

Without the limitations of Google Tag Manager the above could be written

```
const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign(...products));
```

which ends up being a cleaner solution than my original answer.

```js
const products = [{ 'name': 'Test Product 1', 'variant': 'Blue' }, { 'name': 'Test Product 2', 'id': '12345', 'price': '15.25', }]

const keys = Object.keys(Object.assign(...products));

console.log(keys.join(', '))
```

---

**Original Answer**

You can simply [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which can be converted back to an array, here using [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const products = [{ 'name': 'Test Product 1', 'variant': 'Blue' }, { 'name': 'Test Product 2', 'id': '12345', 'price': '15.25', }]

const keys = [...new Set(products.flatMap(Object.keys))];

console.log(keys.join(', '))
```

Comment: MDN says [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is "slightly more efficient" +1

Comment: I think GTM can't read the dots (...new) for some reason because I get the following:
 mismatched input '.' expecting {'~', 'function', 'null', 'typeof', 'undefined', 'getContainerVariable', String, Number, Boolean, '++', '--', '-', '!', Identifier, ']', '{', '[', '('}
Offending token '.' at 26,14.

Comment: @JHorizon edited with specific GTM API snippet

Comment: @pilchard, omg thank you so much! I'm going to fiddle with it a bit. I missed your last comment. I'll keep you posted. Even if this does not work, I want to thank you for your effort!

Comment: I've tried your new solution and get the following error: 1 Error(s) parsing the input:
mismatched input '=>' expecting {')', ','}
Offending token '=>' at 16,43.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't recognize the arrow function?

Comment: That's possible, try it with just a standard function (edited above).

Comment: That gives me the following.
1 Error(s) parsing the input:
extraneous input '[' expecting {Identifier, ')'}
Offending token '' at 14,38.

Comment: It's driving me nuts. There must be a way to return a Key whenever a Value is ''...

Comment: Ohh, possibly doesn’t support  destructuring.

Comment: Edited removing destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const products =  [{
    'name': 'Test Product 1',
    'variant': 'Blue'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Test Product 2',
    'id': '12345',
    'price': '15.25',
  }
]


const keys = products.reduce((res, p) =>  [...res, ...Object.keys(p)], [])

const keyString = [...new Set(keys)].join(', ')

console.log(keyString)
```

Comment: I like the way this uses [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) +1

Answer (score 0):

It's a straight forward solution. Just loop over the object's keys

```js
var products = [{
        'name': 'Test Product 1',         
        'variant': 'Blue'
       },
       {
        'name': 'Test Product 2',         
        'id': '12345',
        'price': '15.25',
       }]
const keys = []
products.forEach(obj => {
  for(item in obj){
    if(!keys.includes(item)){
      keys.push(item)
    }
  }
})
let result = keys.join(', ')
console.log(result)
```